# AWS Elastic Beanstalk execute wget in cronjob

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, wget, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to run a wget command every minute that simply hits a url. I currently have the following in a file called project.config in the .ebextensions folder:

01_test_cron:
        command: * * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://name.of.url

It currently does not execute - are there any glaring errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, Elastic Beanstalk instances auto-scale, you need to consider a few things. Does the cron run on every instance as its setup or just the leader instance? For the second option, here are the contents you should have in your `project.config` file:

```
container_commands:
    01_remove_old_cron_jobs:
        command: "crontab -r || exit 0"
    02_cronjobs:
        command: "cat .ebextensions/crontab | crontab"
        leader_only: true
```

The contents of the `.ebextensions/crontab` file would be:

`* * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null http://name.of.url`

**Updated on March 9, 2015**

You will also need to add a blank line at the end of the `project.config` file as per the YAML syntax.

Comment: Thanks Noman. I've updated it as suggested as the cron only needs to run on the leader instance but it still doesn't seem to execute the wget. Does wget need to be installed or is it installed by default in the Elastic Beanstalk php environment?

Comment: I've checked and SSH has been installed. When the instance deploys I'm getting this error:

[Instance: i-d0643cee Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build: Command 02_cronjobs failed .

Comment: I can confirm this is now working - I forgot about the YAML syntax and hadn't added a blank line to the end of the project.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Noman's answer worked, but there is some issue I don't understand why.

If I do as the answer suggests, it won't install any cron and getting failed. Later

1. I moved the `crontab` from the `.ebextension/crontab` folder to `projectdir/cronwork/crontab.txt.`
2. renamed with `.txt.`
3. added multiple cron like
4. `0 1 * * */3 /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/cron/task1 >> /var/log/crontask1.log 2>&1`
5. `*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null https://example.com/cron/task2 >> /var/log/crontask2.log 2>&1`
6. // Added blank line in crontab.txt file

In EBS, now It works.